# Calling a function which is inside of a function

Tags: javascript

My C# oriented braincells keep telling me that this should work:

```
var MyApp = function() {
currentTime = function() {
    return new Date();
  };
};

MyApp.currentTime();
```

Clearly it doesn't.  But if a javascript function is an object, shouldn't I be able to call a function that is on the object? What am I missing?

Comment: JavaScript is a function scope language. Also variables declared without `var` become global scope. Give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) a read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentTime` is a global (set when you call `myApp`), not a property of `MyApp`.

To call it, without redefining the function:

```
MyApp();
currentTime();
```

However, it sounds like you want either:

*A simple object*

```
var MyApp = {
    currentTime: function() {
      return new Date();
    };
};

MyApp.currentTime();
```

*A constructor function*

```
var MyApp = function() {
  this.currentTime = function() {
    return new Date();
  };
};

var myAppInstance = new MyApp();
myAppInstance.currentTime();
```

Comment: True (hence the upvote), but I threw up a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code a bit and use this:

```
var MyApp = new (function() {
  this.currentTime = function() {
    return new Date();
  };
})();

MyApp.currentTime();
```

Or you can do this:

```
var MyApp = {
    currentTime: function() {
        return new Date();
    }
};

MyApp.currentTime();
```